# laravel create multiple sessions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-authorization

I am developing laravel 5.1 project.this is for backend and for the api. the api is used by several interfaces as following diagram(c1, c2).all these interfaces authenticated by this api.

** c1,c2 has different domains which connects to one url to login(api.com/login) via API.

c1 - c1.com , c2 - c2.com , API - api.com

[image]

those are differentiate with the parameters you send.that means for c1,

```
{"username":"user","password":"password","brand":"c1"}
```

and for c2,

```
{"username":"user","password":"password","brand":"c1"}
```

lets say a user has accounts with same identical information(same username and passwords are used on both platforms) on c1,c2 platform. so when authenticating this user on c1 with laravel's `Auth::loginUsingId` function it creates session.
then if i try to log in c2, successfully login to c2. but automatically logs out from c1. for this matter i need to have multiple sessions in my project. how can I do this?

Comment: Are c1 and c2 on different domains or subdomains?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter: different domains mate. but c1, c2 both authenticate route redirect to one another domain as follows. c1-c1.com, c2 -c2.com , API- api.com/login

Comment: You can use redis for session driver